# How can I get the value of a particular cell from all worksheets?

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with several worksheets, now I want to get the SUM of all H1 cells across all the worksheets. Is that even possible? How do I do it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use VBA? Because this sounds like a job for VBA.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with a formula or with excel vba code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this:
`=SUM(Sheet1:SheetX!H1)`

Or in VBA:

```
For Each w in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    H1Sum = H1Sum + w.range("H1").Value
Next
```

Comment: I think the VBA script might be the way to go for me since my worksheet names are quite random and will be added to over time. But how do I add a VBA script to my excel?

Comment: Just insert two blank "dummy" sheets, one called "Start" and one called "End", and make sure that they are always the left- and right-most sheets in your workbook. The formula is then: SUM(Start:End!H1) and will always work, irrespective of your sheet names or order.

Answer (score 1):

If the first sheet is *Sheet1* and the last sheet is *Sheet99* then:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet99!H1)
```